# How can arithmetic express claims of the form $\Sigma \vdash \sigma$ when $\Sigma$ is infinite?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

As an example, let $\Sigma$ denote the axioms of ZFC (an infinite set). It is my understanding that the language of arithmetic can be used to express claims of the form $$\Sigma \vdash \sigma$$

where $\vdash$ denotes first-order deducibility. Given that $\Sigma$ is infinite, how is this actually done?

Note that I am **not** claiming that: "since arithmetic is about finite entities, this cannot be done."

Comment: An excellent reference for these and related issues is the book **Models of Peano arithmetic** by Richard Kaye. Although the book centers of $\mathsf{PA}$, the results on *representability* hold in a very general setting.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do that using Gödel numbering. The language of set theory only has one binary relation, and no constants or function symbols. So Gödel numbering is quite simple.

It's not hard to show that the encoding of the schema of replacement is recursive. We can identify whenever $n=\#\varphi$ and therefore we can recognize when an integer encodes the replacement axiom for $\varphi$.

So the Gödel numbers of $\Sigma$ is a recursive set. Now we can talk about sequences of numbers in a recursive fashion, and we can ask when $k$ encodes a finite sequence of sentences which are a proof-sequence (i.e. each number encodes either an axiom from $\Sigma$ or something which was deduced from previous steps using modus ponens, or other previously agreed upon inference rules). Therefore the relation $\operatorname{Pr}(n,k)$ which states that $n=\#\varphi$ and $k$ encodes a proof sequence for $\varphi$ from $\Sigma$ is recursive.

Therefore the statement $\Sigma\vdash\sigma$ is really just saying that there exists a proof sequence whose initial axioms are from $\Sigma$ and its last point is $\sigma$. All in all, this relation is recursively enumerable, as the statement is $\exists k\operatorname{Pr}(\#\sigma,k)$.

Answer (score 3):

The infinitude of $\Sigma$ comes from the Axiom Schemas of Replacement and Comprehension, so one has to look into the recursive nature of predicates and formulas. So fortunately $\Sigma$ is not an arbitrary infinite set, but it is *recursively enumerable* using a finite set of rules. And as such it is possible to express "$\phi$ is an axiom of ZFC" (or rather "$n$ is the Gödel number of an axiom of ZFC") in essentially the same way as "$n$ is a prime number" or "$n$ is a power of $10$" are representable.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that $\Sigma$ is recursive, not just R.E., the schema is schematic. And we can easily ask whether or not a statement has the wanted structure for a "correct" $\varphi$ in the language (i.e. the right number of variables, and so on).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Being r.e. implies being recursive in this setting. That is, any theory admitting an r.e. axiomatization admits a recursive one. This is sometimes called Craig's trick, it dates from the early 1950s.

Comment: @Andres: I see. Although what you said seems to be slightly inaccurate. It seems that if $\Sigma$ is RE then it has a recursive axiomatization; but it doesn't imply that $\Sigma$ itself is recursive. I meant the latter. Of course that the two are equivalent for all purposes, though, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I meant "A theory is r.e. iff it is recursive" in the sense I explained, which is the standard sense. Unfortunate that yes, the literal meaning of the sentence is false, of course--so, do not use it :-). And yes, in just about all cases of interest, the given axiomatizations are already recursive to begin with.